# inputting mathworks credentials through shell script

Tags: docker, matlab

I am trying to run this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mathworks/matlab), but it asks that I should enter mathworks credentials.

This is what the log file says:

```
Please enter your MathWorks Account email address and press Enter:
Please enter your MathWorks Account password and press Enter:
```

How can I pass my MathWorks Account email and password? can it be done through shell script?

I also have a license.lic file, but I can't find any example of its use.

Comment: I'm not familiar with matlab licensing but there is the `MLM_LICENSE_FILE` environment variable (documented under Environment variables) that you can set. I guess you can set the variable with `-e MLM_LICENSE_FILE=/license.dat` and bind the license file into the container using `-v ./license.lic:/license.dat`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a license file you need to bind mount the license file location into the container and the use MLM_LICENSE_FILE to point MATLAB to it:

So, assuming your license.lic is in a licenses folder :

```sh
docker run -it --rm -v ./licenses:/licenses -e MLM_LICENSE_FILE=/licenses/license.lic --shm-size=512M mathworks/matlab:r2021b
```